# Help needed in determining the function F for given conditions - Linear Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am currently working on a problem involving a function and need some assistance in finding the function itself. The problem statement is as follows:

We have a function given by $f(x) = Kx + M$, and two equations related to this function. They are:

1. $f(a+4) - f(a) = -12$
2. $f(-7) = 4M$

I am tasked with determining the function F based on these conditions. However, I am unsure about how to proceed and would greatly appreciate any help or guidance.

Here's what I have attempted so far:

First, let's expand the expression $f(a+4) - f(a) = -12$ using the definition of the function:
$K(a+4) + M - (Ka + M) = -12$

Simplifying the equation, we get:
$4K = -12$

Dividing both sides by 4, we find:
$K = -3$

Moving on to the second equation, $f(-7) = 4M$, we can substitute the value of K that we just found:
$(-3)(-7) + M = 4M$

Simplifying further, we have:
$21 + M = 4M$

Subtracting M from both sides, we get:
$21 = 3M$

Dividing both sides by 3, we find:
$M = 7$

At this point, I have determined the values of K and M, which are -3 and 7, respectively. However, I am unsure how to use this information to find the function F itself.

Could someone please guide me through the remaining steps to determine the function F based on these conditions? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: your function is $f(x)=-3x+7$, why couldn't it be?

Answer (score 0):

If you have determined the values of $K$ and $M$ you have $f$ completely determined as $$f(x)=-3x+7, $$ which is just the equation of the line with slope $-3$ that passes trough $(0, 7)$.